# SQL merge result of two queries

Tags: mysql, sql

Both queries use the same table (here: test)

First query:

```
SELECT `test` as t1, COUNT( * ) as t2
FROM  `test_table`
WHERE  `test` > 5
GROUP BY `test`
```

returns result in form

```
--------------------------------------------------
| t1 | t2 |
--------------------------------------------------
|  6 |  2 |
--------------------------------------------------
|  8 |  7 |
--------------------------------------------------
```

Second query:

```
SELECT TRUNCATE(((num1/num2) * 100),3) as t3
FROM
(SELECT COUNT( * ) as num1
FROM `test_table`
WHERE test > 5
group by `test`) a,
(SELECT COUNT( * ) as num2
FROM `test_table`
WHERE test > 5) b
```

returns result in form

```
--------------------------------------------------
| t3      |
--------------------------------------------------
| 40.456% |
--------------------------------------------------
| 59.544% |
--------------------------------------------------
```

What I would like to have is:

```
--------------------------------------------------
| t1 | t2 | t3 |
--------------------------------------------------
|  6 |  2 | 40.456% |
--------------------------------------------------
|  8 |  7 | 59.544% |
--------------------------------------------------
```

How can I do it ? Union puts the t3 results below t1 t2, perhaps join statement ? But join on what ? Or can I make a one query from these two which selects all the data?

Comment: Where do you get 40.456 from . 2/9*100 = 22.222?

Comment: @P.Salmon I don't get 40.456. I wrote "returns result in form" which means there is a number with three decimal places. You can imagine I don't have two rows in my table but many so I just came up with an example.

Comment: For next time, please see: [Why should I provide an MCVE for what seems to me to be a very simple SQL query?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-an-mcve-for-what-seems-to-me-to-be-a-very-simple-sql-query)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This can be done with a few modifications of your second query:

```
SELECT a.t1, num1 as t2, TRUNCATE(((num1/num2) * 100),3) as t3
FROM
(SELECT `test` as t1, COUNT( * ) as num1
FROM `test_table`
WHERE test > 5
group by `test`) a,
(SELECT COUNT( * ) as num2
FROM `test_table`
WHERE test > 5) b
```

Answer (score 1):

Using subquery in the select makes it quite readable

```
   DROP TABLE IF EXISTS TEST_TABLE;
    CREATE TABLE TEST_TABLE(TEST INT);
    INSERT INTO TEST_TABLE VALUES
    (6),(6),
    (8),(8),(8),(8),(8),(8),(8);

    SELECT `test` as t1, COUNT(*) as t2, 
            TRUNCATE(COUNT(*) / (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM TEST_TABLE WHERE TEST > 5) * 100,3) AS T3
    FROM  `test_table`
    WHERE  `test` > 5
    GROUP BY `test`
```

Result

```
+------+----+--------+
| t1   | t2 | T3     |
+------+----+--------+
|    6 |  2 | 22.222 |
|    8 |  7 | 77.777 |
+------+----+--------+
2 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT 
    Z.t1, Z.t2, Z1.t3
FROM
    (SELECT 
        `test` AS t1, COUNT(*) AS t2
    FROM
        `test_table`
    WHERE
        `test` > 5
    GROUP BY `test`) Z
        INNER JOIN
    (SELECT 
        t1, TRUNCATE(((num1 / num2) * 100), 3) AS t3
    FROM
        (SELECT 
        test t1, COUNT(*) AS num1
    FROM
        `test_table`
    WHERE
        test > 5
    GROUP BY `test`) a, (SELECT 
        COUNT(*) AS num2
    FROM
        `test_table`
    WHERE
        test > 5) b) Z1 ON Z.t1 = Z1.t1;
```

Try above code.

Hope this will help you.

Comment: Why do you even need a join? Am I missing something subtle in the question?

Answer (score 0):

The way it is structured in your example you should be able to join them on test_table.test   (the Field you are using Group By on)